# Changing modal content on MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal, and I'like to have 2 steps on it.
The first contains a (kind of) grid with one button on each line. When the user clicks a button, I have to go to other view sending the row's id selected. He may want to go back and change his selection.

I've tried this below, but it opens at the page, not at the modal:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Step2");
}
```

Is there any way to do this?
Tks.

Comment: Since the modal window would have to be opened by javascript/clicking something with the `data-toggle="modal"`, I'd suggest maybe something like including a query string and checking for that query string on page load. If it's present, show the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you following approaches in order get that behavior:

- Javascript: your modal should contain markup for 2 steps, but only one is visible at the moment; one user clicks button on the first step - populate 2nd step dynamically with javascript
- AngularJS + Route: Similar to the previous, but different from tools stand point; angular knows how to insert peaces of html into your page; see a nice [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) with a demo on this; this approach might require some conceptual changes to your solution, but finally you'll be sutisfied

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Step1 action should return a PartialViewResult.
In your grid, upon click the link that open step1, fire a JavaScript function that does the following:

1- fire ajax request to the action passing a query string parameter, ex: ID, you can pass this parameter when you draw the link in the grid, ex: Open

2- In the action, get the parameter, retrieve the data and return the partial view.

3- when the data comes from the ajax request, set its content to the modal dialog

4- show the modal dialog, you can use either bootstrap or jquery dialog